# How to change the look of the maps.google api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, geocoding

Is it possible to use the google.maps api and alter the style and look of the map without changing the size so you can use geocoding to find the location of certain things?

We want to be able to still use the coordinates that you get from geocoding, but be able to change the "style" of the map (colors, details like streets, etc)

Comment: This question does not make sense. What does "look and feel" have to do with geocoding?

Comment: We want to be able to still use the coordinates that you get from geocoding, but be able to change the "style" of the map (colors, details like streets, etc)